# Bibliography and citations with Xaringan and RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan, remarkjs

I'm using the R package xaringan to produce nice slides using RMarkdown. The package RefManageR works quite well in combination with xaringan to handle the bibliography. However, when rendering slides to show all references, I have to specify where to split the bibliography by using something like on a first slide

```
PrintBibliography(myBib, start = 1, end = 10)
```

and then

```
PrintBibliography(myBib, start = 11, end = 20)
```

Do you know a way to automatically split the bibliography so that it shows all references, with let's say  10 references on each slide ?

Thanks for your help